# Get comments posted by a given user

Tags: jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get the comments posted by a given user say 'xyz'

I have checked with below code and it fetches comments based on post id.

```
jQuery.ajax({
async: false,
cache:false, 
url:"https://graph.facebook.com/"+post_id+"/comments?summary=true&limit=25&access_token="+token_here+"",
dataType: "jsonp",
success:function (data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) { 
        var data=data.data;
},
error:function()
{ 
},
complete:function () 
{ 
} 
});
```

Is there any functionality which retrieves the comments for a specific user id?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any functionality which retrieves the comments for a specific user id?

No, there is not.

You can only query comments by the objects they are made upon, but not by who made them.